# How to display another xml as the child list item when I click on the parent list item

Tags: expandablelistview

I am trying to implement expandable List View but when I click on the parent list item, I want to display another xml as the child list item, which has two buttons with some functionalities. It should display the contents of the child.xml is the expanded list view. Is it possible to do this? I have gone through various posts relating to Expandable List View but I haven't got a solution yet.
The Code that I have implemented is as follows:

MainActivity.class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ExpandableListView mEventList;
private String[] eventMenuTitles = {Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4, Item5};
Integer[] imgid={R.drawable.logo,R.drawable.logo,R.drawable.logo,R.drawable.logo,R.drawable.logo};
private String[][] children;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // load slide menu items
    eventMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.event_drawer_items);
   // eventMenuIcons = getResources().getInteger(R.array.event_drawer_icons);
    children = new String [][] {
            { "Content1" },
            { "Content2" },
            { "Content3" },
            { "Content4" },
            {"Content5"}
        };

    mEventList=(ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1);
    mEventList.setAdapter(new ExpandableListAdapter(eventMenuTitles, children));
    mEventList.setGroupIndicator(null);

}

public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private final LayoutInflater inf;
    private String[] groups;
    private String[][] children;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(String[] groups, String[][] children) {
        this.groups = groups;
        this.children = children;
        inf = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return groups.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return children[groupPosition].length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return groups[groupPosition];
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return children[groupPosition][childPosition];
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

         ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.activity_contents, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.text.setText(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).toString());

            return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.activity_list, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.text.setText(getGroup(groupPosition).toString());

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView text;
    }

}
}
```

activity_contents.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3"
    android:src="@drawable/logo" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:onClick="add"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:gravity="center"
android:weightSum="1" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/logo" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:layout_weight="0.8"
    android:gravity="center|left" />

</LinearLayout>
```

As shown, activity_contents.xml has an imageButton and a button, and onClick of each I want some function to be performed. But, maximum I can get is the xml to be displayed on click of the parent item. How can I add some functionality onClick of the button in activity_contents.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found a solution for the above mentioned question. It is as follows:

MainActivity.class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ExpandableListView mEventList;
private String[] eventMenuTitles = {Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4, Item5};
Integer[] imgid={R.drawable.logo,R.drawable.logo,R.drawable.logo,R.drawable.logo,R.drawable.logo};
private String[][] children;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

// load slide menu items
eventMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.event_drawer_items);
// eventMenuIcons = getResources().getInteger(R.array.event_drawer_icons);
children = new String [][] {
        { "Content1" },
        { "Content2" },
        { "Content3" },
        { "Content4" },
        {"Content5"}
    };

mEventList=(ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1);
mEventList.setAdapter(new ExpandableListAdapter(eventMenuTitles, children));
mEventList.setGroupIndicator(null);

}

public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private final LayoutInflater inf;
private String[] groups;
private String[][] children;

public ExpandableListAdapter(String[] groups, String[][] children) {
    this.groups = groups;
    this.children = children;
    inf = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return groups.length;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return children[groupPosition].length;
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return groups[groupPosition];
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return children[groupPosition][childPosition];
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

     ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.activity_contents, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
           holder.btn = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
holder.button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
                        //Your Code
             }
         });
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.text.setText(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).toString());

        return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.activity_list, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.text.setText(getGroup(groupPosition).toString());

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView text;
    Button btn;
}

}
}
```

The rest is the same. :)